# linq compare with previous item

Tags: linq

I need to filter a list, by removing all items have the same language code as the item before (the items are orderd by time). This way, I want to detect all border crossings.

Is there a way to do this with one line of linq?

```
var test = new List<Sample> {   new Sample("AT", "test1"),
                                new Sample("AT", "test2") ,
                                new Sample("AT", "test3") ,
                                new Sample("DE", "test4") ,
                                new Sample("DE", "test5") ,
                                new Sample("DE", "test6") ,
                                new Sample("AT", "test7") ,
                                new Sample("AT", "test8") ,
                                new Sample("AT", "test9") 
                            };


var borderChanges = new List<Sample>();
var lastCountry = ""; 
foreach (var sample in test)
{
    if (sample.country != lastCountry)
    {
        lastCountry = sample.country;
        borderChanges.Add(sample);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is what are you looking for:

```
test.Where((x,idx) => idx == 0 || x.Country != test[idx - 1].Country));
```

Comment: Also a nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else is curious to see, how this problem can be solved with Aggregate(), here is the answer:

```
var borderChanges = test.Take(1).ToList();
test.Aggregate((last, curr) =>
{
    if (last.Code != curr.Code)
    {
        borderChanges.Add(curr);
    }
    return curr; 
});
```

Aggregate() executes the lambda expression for every element in the list, except the first. So we initialize the list with the first item.

In the lamda we add all items where the current item doesnt equal the aggregated value. In our case the aggredated value is always the previously checked item.

Answer (score 0):

In the `foreach` iteration, access to neighboring elements of the sequence is impossible. Perhaps your goal can be achieved with the [Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx) extension method for `IEnumerable<T>`, where you can compare neighboring elements of the sequence.